# Underpromoting in Chess

Tags: chess

I can see how promoting a pawn to a knight can be beneficial if it can attack immediately in L-shape. However is it ever beneficial to promote a pawn to a bishop or a rook, instead of a queen in standard Chess?

Comment: Please see SE Board & Card Games question: [Is pawn promotion to rook or bishop something that is seen in play?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6739/is-pawn-promotion-to-rook-or-bishop-something-that-is-seen-in-play)

Comment: And on Chess.SE: [What are some examples of promoting a pawn to a rook or bishop?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/725/7297)

Comment: Thanks for the links!

Comment: I'm closing this question because it's neither a puzzle nor a question about puzzles. I'm not migrating to Chess because I think if I did it would be closed as a duplicate there :-).

Comment: Sure that makes sense.

Comment: See also: [Uncommon underpromotion motive](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/96749/uncommon-underpromotion-motive)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, one of the most common way for underpromotion to rook/bishop is

> avoiding immediate stalemate (or a stalemate threat, such as a desperado piece) when promoting to a queen (and when a knight promotion is not enough).